# How can I edit php5.conf?

Tags: php

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

PHP is not running on my server after updating Virtualmin. Google suggests that I edit this file: `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf`

(and comment out the two SetHandler lines).

When I do that and try to save it I get a permission error:

```
550 php5.conf: Permission denied
: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
```

I am using FTP on a Windows desktop to look at the files. I can see the permission is 0777

How can I edit this file?

(I am from a Windows background and have just started with Ubuntu. If I can do this using FTP that would be great!)

Comment: DO you have SSH remote on server?

Answer (score 1):

Login to your machine via `SSH`.

Make a backup of the file:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf.bak
```

To edit the file type:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
```

change the file as you need and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> twice.

Comment: Thanks for your info. 
Does your suggestion to use SSH get around the permission issue I found using FTP?
I haven't used SSH and will need to do a lot of Googling to get started. Can I use FTP instead?

Comment: @hotel: Honestly if you gonna work with Linux you need SSH. It is easier than you think. Use [this](https://bvdl.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/BvSshClient-Inst.exe) tool.

Comment: Thanks, I installed the tool and can log in. I typed the $ sudo cp ... line. It replied: [sudo] password for mysite: How do I type it in. All I get is Sorry, try again. Now I have 3 incorrect password attempts! Can I copy and paste in this window? (Getting late here - I'll do more research tomorrow).

Comment: @hotel: You can paste by `right click` with this tool.

Comment: Thanks. When I paste in the password, it says: mysite is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported. Does this mean something to you? (Also, can I paste a screenshot here?)

Comment: @hotel: Then you are not a member of `root` users (`Administrators` equivalent in `Windows`). Ask for such permission from your host/server admin.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your helpful comments. I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: your solution worked. I was confused because the php5.conf changed in /mods-available/ and not in /mods-enabled/, which was where I was working as per your instructions.

When I restarted Apache, everything worked again!! Thanks so much for all your help.